# Is a class with empty body an incomplete type?

Tags: c++, class, declaration, definition, incomplete-type

a class declaration makes the class an incomplete type, so no object of the class could be defined. And the definition of an incomplete type is that its member are not specified. Doesn't that means a class with empty body with no member specified in its definition makes it an incomplete type?

```
class Empty { };

Empty e1; // okay, but why?
```

Comment: A class with an empty body has all its members defined. There just are not very many.

Comment: @dionadar, that should be an answer as it's utterly correct ;)

Comment: @AndyProwl is awake - I know he types faster than I do :D

Comment: @dionadar what are the members defined I wonder?

Comment: @user14042, what dionadar means is that the empty class has all it's members defined.  It has no members defined, so that is all of them! :)

Comment: @user14042 The defaulted member functions (trivial constructor, copy constructor, move constructor and destructor), that is all.

Comment: I suppose the default `operator new` and `operator new[]` functions could also be considered members. Not sure how that works technically though.

Comment: @Moo-Juice okay, got it. As suggest by RandyGaul, there seems to be something contained in e1. Or the one byte returned by sizeof() just guarantee the existence of such object?

Comment: @dionadar ah, true. Forgot those compiler-generated constructors.

Comment: The standard guarantees that any object requires at least one byte, such that the addresses of different objects are different.

Answer (score 4):

> Is a class with empty body an incomplete type?

No, a class with an empty body is simply an empty class, but still a fully defined one. An incomplete type is a type whose full definition is not visible.

```
class Empty;

// Here, Empty is an incomplete type

class Empty { };

// Here, Empty is a complete type
```

Per paragraph 3.9/5 of the C++11 Standard:

> A class that has been declared **but not defined**, or an array of unknown size or of incomplete element type, is
>   an incompletely-defined object type. Incompletely-defined object types and the void types are incomplete
>   types (3.9.1). Objects shall not be defined to have an incomplete type.

Also, per paragraph 9.2/2:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the class-specifier. [...]

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it is not an incomplete type.  In C++ there are times when this kind of thing is desirable.

Consider the following:

```
template<class T>
class Field
{
public:
    virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
};
```

How can I store this in a collection?  Answer is, I can't.  But I could do:

```
class FieldBase 
{
public:
    virtual ~FieldBase() = 0 { }; // virtual destructor needed, but no other members
    virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
};
```

Now, technically, that doesn't have any members defined, as per your question.  It's abstract.  It cannot be instantiated.  But now we can do:

```
template<class T>
class Field : public FieldBase
{
     virtual std::string toString() const { /* ... */ };
};
```

I know this slightly deviates from your original question, but it does illustrate that a base-class has nothing defined (except intent), and we can now store these template-classes in a `std::vector<FieldBase*>` collection.

Comment: the base class's pure virtual function makes a class an incomplete type?

Comment: @user14042, well it's not incomplete.  As has been pointed out before, the compiler will give you some default constructors and copy constructors for free out of the box.  I was merely highlighting that a class that fundamentally does nothing isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Perhaps you meant in a `std::vector<FieldBase*>` collection? Since `FieldBase` is abstract, you cannot store objects of that type by value inside the vector

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a complete type. When I last checked the size is one byte (at least on MS's compiler).

In order to create an incomplete struct omit your braces:

```
struct Empty;
```

This is also known as a forward declared structure, and is not a definition of the struct.

Comment: I also checked its size by sizeof(), and it returns 1 byte in GCC. I wonder what does the object contain?